# How to run task scheduler locally on Laravel 7?

Tags: laravel

I want to learn how to use task scheduler in Laravel 7

According to the documentation, I created a task that should send out a test message to the mail on Mondays at 16:00. Judging by the documentation for local development, there is no need to add a cron entry. I just run the command `php artisan schedule:work` get this error `Command "schedule:work" is not defined.` Where am I making a mistake?

```
 protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
  {
   $schedule->call(function () {
       $test = 'test';
       $email = Emails::where('id', 1)->first();

       Mail::to($email)->send(new TestMail($test));
    })->mondays()->at('16:00');
}
```

After I tried to add the line  `* * * * * cd /public_html/my_project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` but got the following message `bash: README_CI.md: command not found`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
  protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('demo:cron')
                 ->everyMinute();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have `cd /your/path`. better do `php /public_html/my_project/artisan schedule:run` as cd'ing in cronjob does not work unless you have a bash script instead of inline.

as for `schedule:work`, that commmand should exist, does `artisan` (without arguments produce a list of options including `schedule:work`?